# Yii2 renderPartial clientSide validation doesn't work

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-validation

renderPartial clientSide validation doesn't work. I want to render part of form with ajax. Ex.:
**_form.php**

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'options' => [
        'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
    ]
]); 
$form->field($model, 'category_id')->dropDownList($category, [
'onchange'=>'
    $.get( "'.Url::toRoute('/controller/params').'", { id: $(this).val() } )
           .done(function( data ) {
                     $( "#offers-param-content" ).html( data );
           }
     );'
]);
```

**Controller.php**

```
public function actionParams($id)
{
    $model = new Param();
    $params = EavAttribute::find()->where(['category_id'=>$id])->all();
    $this->renderPartial('_params', ['model' => $model, 'params' => $params];
}
```

**_params.php**

```
foreach($params as $item){
    echo Html::activeTextInput('text', $model, $item->name);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried uisng [renderAjax()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html#renderAjax%28%29-detail)?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to enable client validation, then set this property to true.

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'options' => [
        'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
    'enableClientValidation'=>true

    ]
]);
```

And use renderAjax() function in place of renderPartial() it  will inject into the rendering result with JS/CSS scripts and files which are registered with the view

Answer (score 0):

In your `Controller.php` you need to set `layout` to `false` and `die` the execution

```
public function actionParams($id)
{
    $this->layout = false;
    $model = new Param();
    $params = EavAttribute::find()->where(['category_id'=>$id])->all();
    $this->renderPartial('_params', ['model' => $model, 'params' => $params];
    die;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your not returning any validation errors from your controller to your view. 
To archive that use

> yii\widgets\ActiveForm::validate($yourModel);

If your not using activeform you can return errors by

```
$model->getErrors();//will return errors from $model->validate()
```

From your excerpt try this

```
public function actionParams($id) {
        $model = new Param();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
                Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
                return ActiveForm::validate($model); /* Validation error messages are returned by this static function */
            }
            $params = EavAttribute::find()->where(['category_id' => $id])->all();
            $this->renderPartial('_params', ['model' => $model, 'params' => $params]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the partial does not render the required asset scripts and the actual form registration. Create the class below which has two methods the first simply renders the form registration as other answers have stipulated and the second renders the Yii js files containing the actual libraries, I discovered two which are **yii.validation.js** and **yii.activeForm.js** and the method registers and retrieves their proper location such as **assets/ea6a7d55/yii.activeForm.js**.

Please note you only need to load the JS files once and load them before calling the *renderClientValidation* method.

```
class PartialClientValidation {
    
    /**
     * Renders the JavaScript validation code for Yii active form.
     * @param \yii\web\View $view
     * @param \yii\widgets\ActiveForm $form
     */
    public static function renderClientValidation($view, $form) {
        echo "<script>\n";
        $form->registerClientScript(); 
        foreach ($view->js as $codeblocks) {
            foreach ($codeblocks as $codeLine) {
                echo $codeLine."\n";
            }
        }
        echo "</script>\n";
    }
    
    /**
     * renders required Yii script files in their proper contexts.
     * @param \yii\web\View $view
     * @return array
     */
    public static function renderRequiredScriptFiles($view) {
        $scriptFiles = [];
        $formAsset = \yii\widgets\ActiveFormAsset::register($view);
        foreach ($formAsset->js as $f) { $scriptFiles[] = $formAsset->baseUrl.'/'.$f; }
        $validationAsset = \yii\validators\ValidationAsset::register($view);
        foreach ($validationAsset->js as $f) { $scriptFiles[] = $validationAsset->baseUrl.'/'.$f; }
        foreach ($scriptFiles as $scriptFile) {
            echo "<script src=\"$scriptFile\"></script>\n";
        }
        return $scriptFiles;
    }
    
 }
```

To use the above class simply call one or both of the function inside the partial view file like

```
PartialClientValidation::renderRequiredScriptFiles($this);
PartialClientValidation::renderClientValidation($this, $form);
```

Where **$this** referes to the view and **$form** is obtain through calling

> $form = ActiveForm::begin()